# Is there a way for users only saved in the contact form 7 database to view a wordpress private page?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

Originally, I have it this way, every time a user signs up using the contact form 7 it will give the user a subscriber role allowing it to view the private page. The problem with this one is it keeps creating a new user under the users profile in the admin dashboard and emails the user their own Wordpress username and password and I don't want that. I just want a simple view allowing the users in the contact form 7 database to view that private page. I'm really out of options, can anyone suggest another alternative?

```
add_action ('admin_init','add_sub_caps');
 
function add_sub_caps() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $role = get_role('subscriber');
    $role->add_cap('read_private_pages');
}
```

Comment: If you don't want user accounts how do you want your users to sign in? Or is filling in the form the sign-in? i.e. get CF7 to set a cookie once they've signed up which grants access to the page? Or make it a password-protected page and email them a password with the form? (With a bit of work you could make this a unique per-user password.) Or stick with what you've got but filter out subscribers from the dashboard user view by default?

Comment: Just filling in the form is enough, they don't need to sign in. I just want the specific page to be viewable only for users who filled in the form. The form actually redirects you to the that specific page. The subscribers are already filtered the problem is they have to take another step tologin in Wordpress just to access the private page.

Comment: You could make the form set an authentication cookie as well as creating the user and sending a password reset? Although then there's no need for your users to enter a real email address.

Comment: If you need to give them access immediately after the form submission, and only that one time, then you could simply use a unique [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) which you test on the [template_redirection](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) hook.  Else if you need to give them access beyond the initial submission session then you will need to implement @Rup cookie suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is a way to solve this.

You need to save the submitted data into a [transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) and access it from the redirected page where you can confirm the visitor has actually filled in the form.  No need for a private page, but rather use a custom page template to view your restricted page and check if the user has access rights at the top of the page template, else redirect them.

You can do this by,

Step 1: identify the current submission (this works even for non-logged in users.) using a WP [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nonce) as a hidden field in your form, as well as place a js script to redirect to your page once a [successful submission event](https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/) is fired using an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) hooked on the cf7 `do_shortcode_tag` display [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/),

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_hidden_fields','add_hidden_nonce');
function add_hidden_nonce($fields){
  $nonce = wp_create_nonce('cf7-redirect-id');
  $fields['redirect_nonce'] = $nonce;
  /*
   hook the shortcode tag filter using an anonymous function 
   in order to use the same nonce and place a redirect js event 
   script at the end of the form. 
  */
  add_filter('do_shortcode_tag', function($output, $tag, $attrs) use ($nonce){
    //check this is your form, assuming form id = 1, replace it with your id.
    if($tag != "contact-form-7" || $attrs['id']!= 1) return $output;
    $script = '<script>'.PHP_EOL;
    $script .= 'document.addEventListener( "wpcf7mailsent", function( event ){'.PHP_EOL;
    //add your redirect page url with the nonce as an attribute.
    $script .= '    location = "http://example.com/submitted/?cf7="'.$nonce.';'.PHP_EOL;
    $script .= '  }'.PHP_EOL;
    $script .= '</script>'.PHP_EOL;
    return $output.PHP_EOL.$script;
  },10,3);
  return $fields;
}
```

Step 2: hook the cf7 action 'wpcf7_mail_sent' once the submission has passed the validation/and email is sent.

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'save_posted_data_into_transient');
function save_posted_data_into_transient(){
  if(isset($_POST['redirect_nonce'])){ //save the data.
    //save the posted data from the form.  Note if you have submitted file fields you will also need to store the $_FILES array.
    set_transient('_cf7_data_'.$_POST['redirect_nonce'], $_POST, 5*60); //5 min expiration.
  }
}
```

Step 3: on your redirect custom page, you can now [access your stored transient](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_transient/) data, place this at the top of your custom page template,

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['cf7']) ){
  $transient = '_cf7_data_'.$_GET['cf7'];
  $data = get_transient($transient);
  //$data['my-text-field']....
}
?>
```

if the transient is missing, invalid, or the cf7 nonce attribute is missing, then simply [redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) to a page informing the user they have to fill in the form to access the page.